# Which chapters of One Punch Man have panels with times showing the characters speed?

Tags: one-punch-man

In one of the last chapters of One Punch Man, manga panels with time stamps appears, which give you an idea how fast certain characters are. I think I've seen panels like this already in One Punch Man, though not sure if it was in other chapters of the manga, or in the similar chapters of the manga in the webcomic.

Which chapters of One Punch Man have panels with times showing the characters speed?